# Существет ли индикатор сохранения (несохранения) изменений в файле

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день!

Специально просмотрел все существующие темы по поводу phpstorm (на данный момент их 38) и не обнаружил ответа на мой вопрос.

Сначала работал в `PhpDesigner`. Например, в `PhpDesigner`, когда ты производишь любые изменения в файле (например, дописал букву, или удалил символ...), то сразу же на данной активной вкладке маленький значок дискеты становится **красным**. Этот значок говорит о том, что в файле есть какие-то изменения и как следствие, файл не сохранен. Сохраняешь файл и значок дискеты снова побледнел. Другими словами, данная иконка дискеты является индикатором сохранения (несохранения) изменений в файле.

**Вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь аналогичный индикатор сохранения (несохранения) изменений в PhpStorm ?**

Сейчас начал осваивать PhpStorm и удивился, что никакого индикатора сохранения (например, с дефолтными настройками, здесь нет)
При этом автосохранение отключено! Нужно вручную нажимать на сохранение!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что-нибудь по данному вопросу.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Поскольку на дефолтных настройках автосохранение включено, то индикатор изменённого файла отключен.  Как включить индиктор рассказано [в справке](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/editor-editor-tabs.html):

```
File | Settings | Раздел IDE Settings | Editor - Editor tabs - Mark modified tabs with asterisk
```

Comment: Спасибо, поставил, работает.
(Однако  могли бы авторы его сделать поцветастей,т.к. довольно мрачный и незаметный :D  )